# How to detect an event is triggered on element itself?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want the event only fired when I click the div itself, the problem is it will also fired when I click the button, which is not what I want.
What should I do?

```js
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log('click div');
});
```

```html
<div class="container" >
    <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the event target matches the current target, and only then run the callback function:

```js
eventOnCurrentElement(".container", "click", e => {
   console.log("clicked div");
});

function eventOnCurrentElement(selector, event, callback) {
  document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener(event, e => {
    if (e.currentTarget === e.target) {
      callback(e)
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<p>Click beside the button:</p>
<div class="container">
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

`e.currentTarget` always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to `e.target` which identifies the element on which the event occurred.

Comment: Thank you! I never knew the `currentTarget`

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your code:

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {

    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Your issue was due to eventPropagation, the `button click` event bubbles up into the `div click` event.

Check [eventPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation) here.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the target is actually the container or a descendant like so:

```
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target !== container)
    return;
  console.log('click div');
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dqaNdR

Answer (score -1):

Check if the target is equal to the currentTarget

```js
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(e.target !== e.currentTarget)
        return false;
    console.log('div');
    //Your code
});
```

```html
<div class="container" >
    <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

If you are using jQuery;

```js
$(document).on('click', '.container', function(event){
    if(event.target !== this)
        return false;
    console.log('div');
    //Your code
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" >
    <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to check event `target` and `currentTarget` as follow code:

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

```js
container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (event.target === e.currentTarget) {
      // any code
      console.log('click div');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a lump of code which completely lacks anything resembling an explanation for what was changed or why it should solve the problem. It reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. (It looks like you are trying to say the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52422769/19068) which was posted a good five minutes before yours).

Comment: I wrote this answer while another answer was published... I didn't know that question was already answered.